# How to select an item from a list dropdown using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing an issue to select the options from a list drop down box in Selenium.

Below is the list box html sample and the Dropbox box.

```
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root Mui-selected MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button Mui-selected"
tabindex="0" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true" data-value="588ad39c8557bd23e3c16059">
(public) ISO<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>

<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="-1"
 role="option" aria-disabled="false" data-value="611e693ad6018009c8f7c681">
(public) public.dwg<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
```

I have tried it using select element and unfortunately the select class is not in my home code hence it is not working.

So I would like to check if there is anyway I could make the Dropbox to be selected without using a select class.

Any help will be appreciated. Hope someone answers this question.

Note: have searched Google and tried many solutions and at the end none of them was working.

[image]

Comment: Are you doing this in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Select class is for drop down built using Select and Option tag. The htmnl that you've shared is using `li tag` so `Select` **will not** work.

**Fix :**

1. Click on drop down bar.
2. Click on the desired option.

**Code :**

Assuming this is in Python, You could do following :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "XPath of drop down bar"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'(public) public.dwg')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```